# Cast created object to interface type

Tags: c#, .net

I'd like to cast a object created dynamically to a specific interface it extends from.

Example:

Dynamically loaded dll:

```
public class Foo: IBar
{
}
```

Actual Program:

```
var obj = code; // load assembly and fetch object
Type type = obj.GetType().GetInterface("IBar");

IBar bar = (type) obj;
```

Obviously this doesn't work since you can't cast to types. Is there any other way?

Comment: why not `IBar bar = (IBar) obj;`? What are your constraints?

Comment: Interface is dynamically loaded via a dll.

Comment: You can still cast it, even if it is dynamically loaded. Or use `as` rather than a cast: `IBar bar = obj as Ibar; if (bar != null) ... do something with bar`

Comment: Ah to clarify: IBar is from a different dll. I can't access the type itself. If I'd do: `(IBar) obj;` I'd get  a Syntax error since there is no type.

Comment: If you can't access it, you can't convert to it. If you have access to it and know the type name, then using `as` should work.

Comment: If you can't access the type, then you can't write `IBar bar = ...`

Comment: There's seldom a need for this since the caller can just cast themselves if they're expecting a particular type. Nevertheless, `Convert.ChangeType` should do it.

Comment: @Lyze "I can't access the type itself", you are contradicting yourself by declaring bar as type `IBar` (`IBar bar`).

Comment: If you don´t know the type at *compile*-time you can´t expect the *compiler* to *cast* which is a compile-time operation. What you want is simply not possible. However you may call any member on `ob` via reflection, e.g. `obj.GetType().GetProperty("MyProperty).GetValue(myInstanceOfFoo, null)`.

Comment: isn't the point to have the definition of the interface in your non-dynamic code, so you can cast to it no matter what it actually does?

Comment: Conversely, if you know what `IBar` should be able to do but you just don't want to reference the interface (for whatever reason), you could leverage `dynamic` and resolve all calls at runtime. This is no help if any interface implementation is private, though.

Answer (score 4):

You should have two dlls. One with intefaces where you implement `IBar`, which is referenced by both program and dynamic lib. And second for dynamic lib.

Then you can normally cast:

```
IBar bar = (IBar) obj;
```